# Elegoo Saturn: artifacts which looks like a slicer bug

Tags: dlp

I have Elegoo Saturn for few days and it makes sometimes artifacts as in the image:

[image]

Elegoo Saturn's support supposes that it is caused by the model support. But to me the artifact looks very "digital". Might a problem with Chitubox in the case of 4k displays.

1. The density of the support structure is typical for default values in Chitubox 1.9.1. More than this and resin sticks between the
   support, makes it difficult for the air to flow, suction appears and
   makes holes in the model.
2. Once the bottom of the cone is printed, it also becomes a support of the higher layer next to be printed. So the
   discrepancy would self-correct itself and disappear in higher parts of the model. But it goes up the cone without any change.
3. The raised part has very sharp borders which form a perfect, precise vertical plane. It looks nothing like a mechanical problem
   with the support.
4. The raised part is very thin, about 0.5 width. A discrepancy between two parts of the model caused by a weak support would create
   a single, possibly wide deformation and not two close, razor-sharp discontinuities
   which precisely continue forever and have a perfect surface between them.
5. The bottom of the cone does not show the arching
   characteristic for a weak support and for a reason: I made the bottom surface slightly
   diagonal to have the layer self-support effect.
6. The problem shows rarely, in about 10% of the cones and if they are accompanied by a large, complex model placed nearby. When I changed the complex model to its never version, the cones printed all without any problems.
7. If you look at the close-up, the layers are perfectly horizontal to the built plate and thus do not show any mechanical problem with the
   support. There is a normal layering visible even on the vertical two shear surfaces.

**What you think about the possible cause?**

Comment: I hope someone answers, but I would say that the proper place to ask is https://www.elegoomars.com/forum/index.php